# how to create an anchor link between 2 table headers of 2 different tables in html

Tags: html, html-table

In one of the requirements, we have to construct many tables in the html document and a table at the top will contains rows (of type anchor links) each pointing to the header of second table till last table. The first row of top table must have anchor tag to point to the header of the second table, 2nd row in top table should point to the header of third table in document and the last row of the top table should point to the header of the last table in the html document.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job, think is quite clear how it works. Simply Link points to id of the table.

```
<html>
    <header></header>
    <body>
        <table>
            <caption>Main Table</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Link</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#table1">Table 1</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><a href="#table2">Table 2</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table id="table1">
            <caption>Table 1</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Header 1</th>
                <th>Header 2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table id="table2">
            <caption>Table 2</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Header 1</th>
                <th>Header 2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```